# Run only tasks with a certain tag or untagged

Tags: ansible

In this  playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: task A
    debug: msg="task A"
    tags:
       - A

  - name: task B
    debug: msg="task B"
    tags:
       - B

  - name: untagged task
    debug: msg="untagged task"
```

I would like to run the task with the tag `A` and the untagged task.

I know about the `--skip-tags` option, but this a simplified example.
 My use case is for a very complex playbook with many tags and roles with tasks with different tags, and interdependencies between tagged and non-tagged tasks. Long story short, the only 'clean' option for me is to run only specified tags and those untagged.

Is there a way to call `ansible-playbook` so that it'll run specific tags and untagged tasks only?
I'm using ansible 2.9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, indeed:

> For example, if you wanted to just run the “configuration” and
>   “packages” part of a very long playbook, you can use the --tags option
>   on the command line:
>
> ansible-playbook example.yml --tags "configuration,packages"

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags*</sup>

Along with:

> There are another 3 special keywords for tags: `tagged`, `untagged` and
>   `all`, which run only tagged, only untagged and all tasks respectively.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags*</sup>

So your solution is:

```
ansible-playbook --tags "untagged,A" playbook.yml
```